# Name for such words like "iceteroid, irmageddon"

Tags: word-request

Is there a name for such words like "**iceteroid**" and "**irmageddon**"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called a [portmanteau](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/portmanteau) words. They are formed by combining existing words that relate to one concept.

If the term becomes accepted as part of the English language, it is called a [neologism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/neologism).